# Airconsole Controller Generator

Tags: airconsole

I am using generator for button controller.
I am having issue to find out which code to use for below mention??
"How to execute the code if a button is touch, send message to screen?"

Sorry I am a beginner in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exemple here: https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-construct2/blob/master/construct2%20projects/pong/controller_resources/js/main.js

Basically, you listen for an event on your button and send a message to the screen:

```
$('#button').on("touchend", function (event) {
    airConsole.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, {
        message: value
    });
});
```